# Insert with Foreign Key Contraints

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

```
CREATE TABLE makeModel(
    makeID INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    modelID INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (makeID , modelID),
    FOREIGN KEY (makeID) REFERENCES make(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (modelID) REFERENCES model(id)
    );

INSERT INTO makeModel (makeID)
    SELECT DISTINCT (make) FROM vehicle;
```

In the above code, I want to add the distinct values from column make from vehicles into column makeID in makeModel but I get the error

> INSERT INTO makeModel (makeID)  SELECT DISTINCT (make) FROM vehicle   Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dealership`.`makemodel`, CONSTRAINT `makemodel_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`modelID`) REFERENCES `model` (`ID`))

Comment: You're not filling in the `model` field, which is required to match a model ID. It's using the default value `0`, which is not a valid model ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert into the `model` field as well, since it's also a foreign key.

```
INSERT INTO makeModel(makeID, modelID)
SELECT DISTINCT make, model
FROM vehicle
```